# Worldpay\Worldpay' not found

Tags: payment-methods, magento-2.1.3, worldpay

I am working on Worldpay payment module to enable Worldpay payment method in my magento 2 website but i got following error while click on place order.

i am using Worldpay module from https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-magento2

```
public function setupWorldpay() {
    $service_key = $this->config->getServiceKey();
    $worldpay = new \Worldpay\Worldpay($service_key); //(line no 221)

    $worldpay->setPluginData('Magento2', '2.0.25');
    \Worldpay\Utils::setThreeDSShopperObject([
        'shopperIpAddress' => \Worldpay\Utils::getClientIp(),
        'shopperSessionId' => $this->customerSession->getSessionId(),
        'shopperUserAgent' => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '',
        'shopperAcceptHeader' => '*/*'
    ]);
    return $worldpay;
}
```

Fatal error: Class 'Worldpay\Worldpay' not found in /public_html/app/code/Worldpay/Payments/Model/Methods/WorldpayPayments.php on line 221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That module depends on worldpay php library. So first intall that library using below command and then try that payment module again.

```
composer require worldpay/worldpay-lib-php
```

Once this library is installed, you will not get that error.

Comment: Ya i totally forgot about it and i just check that module is Tested versions..

Magento 2.0.0 - 2.1.2 so will it support with 2.1.3

Comment: You need to try it. It may support.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that it helped you.