# Unable to get class Worldpay\Worldpay

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, error, worldpay

I have installed the World Pay extension on our `Magento 2.1.8` with no issues. Everything seemed to be just fine. However, on both, live and test mode environments, we can’t successfully complete an order.

When we get to the checkout and want to pay using the World Pay Card payment. Once the credentials are in, press the `Place Order` button and we get an error message: “Error, please try again”. There is nothing in the Google Chrome Console, also nothing in the logs.

When I enable the 3D secure, I get this error in the var > report > api > 1020389781593 :

```
s:1152:"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Class 'Worldpay\Worldpay' not found in /domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/code/Magenest/Worldpay/Model/Methods/WorldpayPayments.php:260
Stack trace:
#0 /domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/code/Magenest/Worldpay/Model/Methods/Card.php(160): Magenest\Worldpay\Model\Methods\WorldpayPayments->setupWorldpay()
#1 /domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/code/Magenest/Worldpay/Model/Methods/Card.php(306): Magenest\Worldpay\Model\Methods\Card->createWorldpayOrder('000000026', Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), 'TEST_RU_0e19564...', '6.95', 'GBP', false, false, Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order))
#2 /domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/code/Magenest/Worldpay/Model/Methods/Card.php(127): Magenest\Worldpay\Model\Methods\Card->createOrder(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), '6.95', false)
#3 /domains/domain.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/CaptureOperation.php(82): Magenest\Worldpay\Model\Methods\Card->capture(Object(Mage' in '/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/code/Magenest/Worldpay/Model/Methods/WorldpayPayments.php' on line 260";
```

The  line 260 is this:

```
public function setupWorldpay()
{
    $service_key = $this->config->getServiceKey();
    $worldpay = new \Worldpay\Worldpay($service_key); ---- line 260

    $worldpay->setPluginData('Magento2', '2.0.25');
    \Worldpay\Utils::setThreeDSShopperObject([
        'shopperIpAddress' => \Worldpay\Utils::getClientIp(),
        'shopperSessionId' => $this->getShopperSessionId(),
        'shopperUserAgent' => '',
        'shopperAcceptHeader' => '*/*'
    ]);
    return $worldpay;
}
```

Anyone with similar error or knows how to solve it?

Comment: Have you check all files are install properly?

Comment: I think so, in installation went fine with no error. I try reinstall it and see if that helps. I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: Seems, you need to run `composer update` to retrieve all dependencies

Comment: did you checked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/178538/20064)?

Comment: It did help. That was it.